# Can't import facebook sdk, conflicting with google play services

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that involves a tab layout. On the third tab I have a Google Map, on the fifth tab I can share my whereabouts on the map in Facebook. I imported Google Play Services for the Google Maps, however I am trying to import the Facebook SDK. Then these errors pop up:

```
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] Versions found are:
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] Path:     C:\Users\user\workspace\QuezonCityGuide\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide]     Length: 556198
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide]     SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] Path: C:\Users\user\Downloads\facebook-android-sdk-3.5.2\facebook-android-sdk-3.5.2\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide]     Length: 349252
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide]     SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-10-17 11:58:48 - QuezonCityGuide] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I'm trying to use the Facebook Share Dialog. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just replace the `android-support-v4.jar` of your project with `android-support-v4.jar` present in `Facebook-SDK>libs` folder

Comment: I can still use Google maps if I do that?

Comment: so It doesn't really matter what android-support-v4.jar I'm going to use?

Comment: Actually the library you are referencing has already the same android jar file which is in your project but with different namespace. So it is clashing when you run the program.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have not added the `android-support-v4.jar` library from your main project's libs folder. If you have done so then it will give library dependency error. Because the Facebook SDK also contains the same library.

So you just have to add Facebook SDK as library in your project by right click `Prefrence>Android>from tab click on Add... and select Facebook SDK.` Also remove your `android-support-v4.jar` from your build path if its referencing from your project.